# output vector of lists pointer class

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Am quite new here. 
Need to output value from a complex container!!
The classes are given below.

```
class CourseClass
{
private:

    Professor* _professor;  // Profesor who teaches

    Course* _course; // Course to which class belongs

    list<StudentsGroup*> _groups; // Student groups who attend class

    int _numberOfSeats; // Number of seats (students) required in room

    bool _requiresLab; // Initicates wheather class requires computers

    int _duration; // Duration of class in hours

public:

    // Initializes class object
    CourseClass(Professor* professor, Course* course, const list<StudentsGroup*>& groups,
        bool requiresLab, int duration);
...
}

class Professor
{

private:

    int _id;  // Professor's ID

    string _name; //Professor Name

    list<CourseClass*> _courseClasses; // List of classes that professor teaches

public:
    // Initializes professor data
    Professor(int id, const string& name);
...
}

class Course
{
private:

    int _id; // Course ID

    string _name; // Course name

public:

    // Initializes course
    Course(int id, const string& name);
...
}

class StudentsGroup
{
private:

    int _id; // Student group ID

    string _name; // Name of student group

    int _numberOfStudents; // Number of students in group

    list<CourseClass*> _courseClasses; // List of classes that group attends

public:

    // Initializes student group data
    StudentsGroup(int id, const string& name, int numberOfStudents);

...
}
```

The vector below is what I want to output, how would I design the loop?

```
vector < list < CourseClass* > > _slots;
```

Comment: Why does _groups contain a pointer to the class rather than a value? In fact, why is that true for all of these member variables?

Comment: ...not sure I follow. The values are later taken from a config.dat file and stored in the container, guess the pointer is used to refer to the different set of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in c++11:

```
for(const auto& course_list : _slots)
{
  for(CourseClass* p: course_list)
  {
    do_something_with(*p);
    // or p->do_something();
  }
}
```

in c++03 it's more tedious:

```
typedef list<CourseClass*> ClassList;
typedef vector<ClassList> ClassListVector;

ClassListVector::const_iterator slot = _slots.begin();
ClassListVector::const_iterator last_slot = _slots.end();
for( ; slot != last_slot ; ++slot)
{
  const ClassList& myClassList = *slot;
  ClassList::const_iterator class = myClassList.begin();
  ClassList::const_iterator class_end = myClassList.end();
  for( ; class != class_end ; ++class)
  {
    CourseClass* p = *class;
    do_something_with(p);
  }
}
```